# Multi where conditions in an mdx query (LINQ to mdx) by Percolator analysis services

Tags: c#, sql, linq, mdx, cube

am trying to apply multiple where conditions on the below linq query :

```
            using (var _DB = new MyDB())
        {
                   var QryYear = from model in _DB.DL
                          where model.BusinessDate.BusinessDate.Years["2016"]
                          where model.BusinessDate.BusinessDate.Years["2017"]
                          where model.NumL.Num[FirstNumber].Function("Lag(2)") | model.NumL.Num[SecoundNumber]
                          select new MdxQuery
                          { OnColumns = model.Amount };
            result = QryYear.Percolate<AmountModel>().ToList();
```

but am getting this exception ({"Query (13, 1) The BusinessDate hierarchy is used more than once in the Crossjoin function."})
this is how the query looks like in mdx:

```
SELECT{Measures.[Amount]} ON 0
 //----------             From / SubCube               ----------
 FROM [DL]
//----------                 Slicers                  ----------
WHERE
([BusinessDate].[BusinessDate].[Years].[2016],  [BusinessDate].[BusinessDate]. 
[Years].[2017]
,   ([DL].[Num].[55].Lag(2) : [DL].[Num].[2305]))}
```

[Percolator analysis services github](https://github.com/mhallmark/PercolatorAnalysisServices)

Answer (score 1):

Braces () in MDX either signify a tuple or crossjoin, you are using braces in the WHERE clause. Try making the two specified years into a set by putting curly braces around them:

```
SELECT{Measures.[Amount]} ON 0
 //----------             From / SubCube               ----------
 FROM [DL]
//----------                 Slicers                  ----------
WHERE
(
{[BusinessDate].[BusinessDate].[Years].[2016],  
[BusinessDate].[BusinessDate]. [Years].[2017]
}
,   ([DL].[Num].[55].Lag(2) : [DL].[Num].[2305]))
```

---

note

Just to confirm.
The following `MDX` is valid:

```
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,
    NON EMPTY [Date].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It returns this:

[image]

But if we move 2 year members to the WHERE clause, like your script, then it is not valid MDX:

```
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE ([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2005], [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2006]);
```

Exception message:

> Executing the query ... Query (4, 1) The Calendar Year hierarchy is
>   used more than once in the Crossjoin function. Run complete

But if you follow my suggestion and add the curly braces then it is valid:

```
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE ( {[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2005], [Date].[Calendar Year].&[2006]});
```

Results in

[image]

Comment: but this is auto generated(produced by the tool percolator) i can only control the linq to mdx code

Comment: Looks like a bug in the tool. I’ll test against Adv Wrks and edit my answer